# IE8 issues with Yammer embed and API

Tags: yammer

Facing multiple issues with IE 8 (detailed version 8.0.7601.17514). Please note everything works fine in other browsers.

1. Yammer embed my feed control is not working. Sometimes it shows result and sometimes not.
2. REST API call not working and giving error as below. However I used new js sdk and new yam.platform.request.

Error is : yam.request is null or not an object. source : platform_js_sdk.js

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the div that you embed yammer feed has to be above the yammer request script

eg.

```
<div id="embedded-feed" style="height:400px;width:500px;"></div> 
    <script>
        yam.connect.embedFeed(
          { container: '#embedded-feed',
            network: 'fourleaf.com'  // network permalink (see below)
        });
    </script>
```

Otherwise, IE will not be able to find the div to show the feed (but chrome works fine..)

Comment: Hi Bernand,Thanks, but my div tag is top of the script which contains embed tag.

Comment: Hi Bernand,Also I observed after continues refresh yam.request is coming undefined from platform_js_sdk.js file.